# Get all Employees for dates from tables for today's and last date

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a query to get all the employees for today's and last date.

I have two columns in_date and out_date. So if there is record for both columns `in_date` and `out_date` I don't want to fetch those records.

I want to fetch only records for today's and yesterday dates who's in_date is set but out_date is not set plus those records who don't even have the in_date and out_date record.

So that in simple words it would be get all records from attendance table whose in_date and out_date are not set. If both are set then don't fetch the record.

This is the query I have so far, not sure I am doing the right way:

```
SELECT 
  `E`.`employee_id` AS EmployeeID,
  `E`.`full_name` AS EmployeeNam,
  `ATT`.`in_date` AS EmployeeInDate,
  `ATT`.`out_date` AS EmployeeOutDate,
  `ATT`.`in_time` AS EmployeeInTime,
  `ATT`.`out_time` AS EmployeeOutTime 
FROM
  (`employee` E) 
  INNER JOIN `employment` ET 
    ON `E`.`employee_id` = `ET`.`employee_id` 
    AND ET.current = 1 
  INNER JOIN `employee_project` EP 
    ON `E`.`employee_id` = `EP`.`employee_id` 
  LEFT JOIN `attendence` ATT 
    ON `ATT`.`employee_id` = `E`.`employee_id`  
  INNER JOIN `posting` P 
    ON `P`.`employement_id` = `ET`.`employment_id` 
    AND P.current = 1 
    AND P.status = 2 
WHERE `E`.`enrolled` = 1 -- AND ATT.`in_date` = CURDATE() - 1 OR ATT.`in_date` = CURDATE()
GROUP BY `E`.`employee_id`
```

This is the record I am getting now:

[image]

I have tried this in where

```
AND ATT.`in_date` = CURDATE() - 1 OR ATT.`in_date` = CURDATE()
```

Not sure it's the right way to get the today's and yesterdays date? If it's not right please also tell what would be the right way getting dates for today and previous.

Plus it doesn't get me the record for the empty dates, how would I get the empty dates?

**Note For Empty:**
I want empty only on case that if employee has not put attendance for today so it's empty, then I want today's empty or last day empty if exist ( not all the empty records ).

### Update

This time I have tried the UNION way, but for NULL the union also unions both nulls? How to then distinct null is for which date?

```
SELECT 
  `E`.`employee_id` AS EmployeeID,
  `E`.`full_name` AS EmployeeNam,
  `ATT`.`in_date` AS EmployeeInDate,
  `ATT`.`out_date` AS EmployeeOutDate,
  `ATT`.`in_time` AS EmployeeInTime,
  `ATT`.`out_time` AS EmployeeOutTime 
FROM
  (`employee` E) 
  INNER JOIN `employment` ET 
    ON `E`.`employee_id` = `ET`.`employee_id` 
    AND ET.current = 1 
  INNER JOIN `employee_project` EP 
    ON `E`.`employee_id` = `EP`.`employee_id` 
  LEFT JOIN `attendence` ATT 
    ON `ATT`.`employee_id` = `E`.`employee_id`  AND ATT.`in_date` = CURDATE() - 1 -- Get Yesterdays Records
  INNER JOIN `posting` P 
    ON `P`.`employement_id` = `ET`.`employment_id` 
    AND P.current = 1 
    AND P.status = 2 
WHERE `E`.`enrolled` = 1
GROUP BY `E`.`employee_id` , ATT.in_date
UNION
SELECT 
  `E`.`employee_id` AS EmployeeID,
  `E`.`full_name` AS EmployeeNam,
  `ATT`.`in_date` AS EmployeeInDate,
  `ATT`.`out_date` AS EmployeeOutDate,
  `ATT`.`in_time` AS EmployeeInTime,
  `ATT`.`out_time` AS EmployeeOutTime 
FROM
  (`employee` E) 
  INNER JOIN `employment` ET 
    ON `E`.`employee_id` = `ET`.`employee_id` 
    AND ET.current = 1 
  INNER JOIN `employee_project` EP 
    ON `E`.`employee_id` = `EP`.`employee_id` 
  LEFT JOIN `attendence` ATT 
    ON `ATT`.`employee_id` = `E`.`employee_id` AND ATT.`in_date` = CURDATE() -- Get Todays Dates
  INNER JOIN `posting` P 
    ON `P`.`employement_id` = `ET`.`employment_id` 
    AND P.current = 1 
    AND P.status = 2 
WHERE `E`.`enrolled` = 1
GROUP BY `E`.`employee_id`
```

[image]

Comment: you need irrespective of the days duration?...that means you need only the records which doesn't set in_date and out_date right!!!!!!!

Comment: @Vamshi.goli Yes thats what i want to get..

Comment: I hope this logic may helps you......when there is null in in_date or out_date then fetch those records

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like that in mysql:

```
WHERE (ATT.in_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 1 DAY) --> today date - 1 day.

take a look to this function   [DATE_SUB](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_sub.asp)

i hope it helps.

Comment: There are two correct records in table with todays date and yesterdays date, plus i am not getting NULL record?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly:

```
AND ATT.in_date BETWEEN CONCAT(CAST(DATE(CURDATE() - 1) AS CHAR), ' 00:00:00') AND CONCAT(CAST(DATE(CURDATE()) AS CHAR), ' 23:59:59') AND (ATT.out_date IS NULL OR ATT.out_date = '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
```

should give you what you want, it's a little messy though :p

**Update**
If you also want the records where in_date and out_date are NULL, try this out:

```
AND (ATT.in_date BETWEEN CONCAT(CAST(DATE(CURDATE() - 1) AS CHAR), ' 00:00:00') AND CONCAT(CAST(DATE(CURDATE()) AS CHAR), ' 23:59:59') AND (ATT.out_date IS NULL OR ATT.out_date = '0000-00-00 00:00:00')) OR (ATT.in_date IS NULL OR ATT.in_date = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND ATT.out_date IS NULL OR ATT.out_date = '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
```

Comment: `
Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT CONCAT(CAST(DATE(CURDATE()) AS CHAR), ' 23:59:59')
GROUP BY `E`.`employee' at line 21`

Comment: Whoops, left a bit of my "testing" code in there. The snippet is updated if you care to try it again. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: yes error went away. the problem is i am only getting result for those employees whose dates are in attendance. but what if todays date is not registered in attendance table i want null or 0000-00-00 for those dates..

Comment: Assuming your default value for out_date is "NULL", I have updated the snippet again that should give you what you want.

Comment: Yes, its more like your updated where, but i am getting wrong dates??
i want for date todays and yesterdays date.. it is showing some really old days also.

Comment: I updated the update by adding some parentheses for more specific grouping of the where clauses.  Give that a try, if it doesn't work try moving the parentheses around to get the grouping right.

Answer (score 0):

```
AND (
      (ATT.`in_date` >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND (ATT.`out_date` IS NULL OR ATT.`out_date` = '0000-00-00'))
    OR 
      ((ATT.`in_date` IS NULL OR ATT.`in_date` = '0000-00-00') AND (ATT.`out_date` IS NULL OR ATT.`out_date` = '0000-00-00'))
    )
```

The above conditions should return records that:

- `ATT.in_date` is either equal to or greater than yesterday's date (assuming you have no records in the future) **AND** `ATT.out_date` is not set (NULL or '0000-00-00')
- **OR**
- `ATT.in_date` is not set (NULL or '0000-00-00') **AND** `ATT.out_date` is not set (NULL or '0000-00-00').